# CSS horizontal bar graph - managing widths

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, graph, bar-chart

I have a site that displays various horizontal bar graphs with different left and right percentages.

Here's a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

All is great until I run into disproportionate bar widths:

[image]

So looking for a little advice here.  How do you recommend handling the widths in this case so that the really low percentages such as 1% can be fully displayed while maintaining some degree of relative proportionality between the two bars?  I've tried padding with pixel width, adding/subtracting buffer width %'s, but nothing to my satisfaction yet.

Here's my current HTML/CSS:

HTML:

```
<div class="graph-outer">
    <div class="inner-left-cap"></div>
    <div class="inner-left-bar">1%</div>
    <div class="inner-right-bar">99%</div>
    <div class="inner-right-cap"></div>
</div>
```

​
CSS:

```
.graph-outer {
    background: black;
    height: 20px;
    width: 150px;   
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-left-cap {
    background: orange;
    width: 1%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.inner-left-bar {
    background: orange;
    width: 1%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

.inner-right-cap {
    background: red;
    width: 1%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.inner-right-bar {
    background: red;
    width: 98%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
```

​http://jsfiddle.net/2ZkDz/126/

Comment: I may be able to use jQuery plugin or Twitter Bootstrap progress bar since I am only dealing with two values: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#progress. However, will have to see how they handle text, which is what's causing the issues.

Comment: Do you need to center the text inside the chart? You could always force them to the edges: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZkDz/128/